# How do I line up my error bars with my bars in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I'm creating a bar chart with a pattern for a subset of the bars, and I want to add error bars.

[image]

However, I'm having trouble lining up the error bars with with the bar charts—I want to have them appear centered on each bar. How do I do this? Moreover, the legend currently does not clearly distinguish the striped and non-striped bars as corresponding to not treated and treated groups.

Finally, I'd like to create version of this plot which stacks adjacent bars (i.e. bars within each facet_grid)—any tips on how to do that would be much appreciated.

The code I'm using is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpattern)

models = c("a", "b")
task = c("1","2")
ratios = c(0.3, 0.4)
standard_errors = c(0.02, 0.02)

ymax = ratios + standard_errors
ymin = ratios - standard_errors

colors = c("#F39B7FFF", "#8491B4FF")

df <- data.frame(task = task, ratios = ratios)
df <- df %>% mutate(filler = 1-ratios)
df <- df %>% gather(key = "obs", value = "ratios", -1)
df$upper <- df$ratios + c(standard_errors,standard_errors)
df$models <- c(models,models)
df$lower <- df$ratios - c(standard_errors,standard_errors)
df$col <- c(colors,colors)
df$group <- paste(df$task, df$models, sep="-")
df$treated <- "yes"
df[df$ratios<0.5,]$treated = "no"

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = ratios, fill = col, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) + 
  stat_summary(aes(pattern=treated),
               fun = "mean", position=position_dodge(), 
               geom = "bar_pattern", pattern_fill="black", colour="black") +
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2, position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
        scale_pattern_manual(values=c("none", "stripe"))+ #edited part
        facet_grid(.~task, 
             scales = "free_x", # Let the x axis vary across facets.
             space = "free_x",  # Let the width of facets vary and force all bars to have the same width.
             switch = "x") + guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 1)) +
      guides(fill = "none")
p
```

Comment: I think it would help if you were to simplify your code example to only include those bits that are relevant to your question. There is a lot of stuff going on here, some of it involving (soft-)deprecated functionality (`gather` has been replaced with `pivot_longer`, `guides` has undergone changes) and other things that are purely aesthetic (and don't seem relevant). Also & IMO, statements such as "for extra points" are usually not perceived positively  around here. This is not an auction site. You're asking strangers to spend *their* time fixing *your* problems; there are no "extra points".

Comment: @MauritsEvers appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I've now made edits to address each of your points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option

```r
df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = models, y = ratios)) +
    geom_col_pattern(
        aes(fill = col, pattern = treated), 
        pattern_fill = "black",
        colour = "black",
        pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.2,
        position = position_dodge()) + 
    geom_errorbar(
         aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, group = interaction(task, treated)), 
         width = 0.2,
         position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
    facet_grid(~ task, scales = "free_x") +
    scale_pattern_manual(values = c("none", "stripe")) + 
    scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

A few comments:

- I don't understand the point of creating `group`. IMO this is unnecessary. TBH, I also don't understand the point of `models` and `task`: if task = "1" then models = "a"; if task = "2" then models = "b"; so task and models are redundant as they encode the same thing (whether you call it "1"/"2" or "a"/"b").
- The reason why you (originally) didn't see a pattern in the legend is because of the scale factor in the legend key. As per `?scale_col_pattern`, you can adjust this with the `pattern_key_scale_factor` parameter. Here, I've chosen `pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.2` but you may want to play with different values.
- The reason why the error bars didn't align with the dodged bars was because `geom_errorbar` didn't know that there are different `task`-`treated` combinations. We can fix this by explicitly defining a `group` aesthetic given by the combination of `task` & `treated` values. The reason why you don't need this in `geom_col_pattern` is because you already allow for different `treated` values through the `pattern` aesthetic.
- You want to use `scale_fill_identity()` if you already have actual colour values defined in the `data.frame`.